# using RegEx to replace string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i have this pattern i using to replace string:

```
var html = "some test string";
var regex = new Regex(@"<(.|\n)+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var result = regex.Replace(html, ?);
```

this pattern matches all html tags `<anything here>` and replace with `?`. actually `?` is `" "` or `""` according to match type. for example if i using below html markup:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
```

result is something like below:

```
Google?Yahoo! (here ? should be " ")
```

and if i using below html markup:

```
Buy it now for <b>$279</b><b>.99</b>!
```

result is something like below:

```
Buy it now for ?$279??.99?! (and here ? should be "")
```

can anybody help to improve this pattern to works properly? thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

OK, actually i not found an approach to do that i need, so I'm using MatchEvaluator to detect where ? should be "" and where " "! thanks a lot of ;)

Comment: So, you want spaces on some cases, and no spaces on others. Define these case, if possible, and you've solved your problem.

Comment: ok, but i can't do this by using RegEx condition statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for your Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<(.|\n)*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

And check your options, there's no need to combine singleLine and MultiLine.

Comment: but if exists any break-line on HTML, then nothing matches

Comment: It shouldn't if it's RegexOptions.SingleLine, it changes the way that the . behaves.

Give it a try without either of the options, it really does works as I copied the expression from live code we use.

Comment: There's no need for the `IgnoreCase` modifier either (no letters in the regex).  And the `Singleline` modifier allows `.` to match linefeeds, so you can get rid of that `(.|\n)` obscenity. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx Coach (http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) or http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (a online tool) to test your regular expressions and get a feeling for them.

Comment: thanks but there isn't better than http://regexhero.net/tester/ an online RegEx tester tools on the web ;)